# cursor jumps to start of body when deleting a content node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, tinymce

I am using the tinymce real time editor. I insert a span (like a bookmark) which i use as a marker in the content (code in own plugin):

```
var rng = ed.selection.getRng();
rng.collapse(true);
ed.marker_id += 1;
rng.insertNode(ed.selection.dom.create('span', {'data-mce-type' : "bookmark", id : 'ir_marker_span'+ed.marker_id , style : ''}, '\uFEFF'));
```

Deleting this marker works as expected using a non-iPad system:

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('#ir_marker_span'+ed.marker_id).remove();
```

On iPad the cursor jumps to the start of the body in this case.
It is crucial for me to be able to remove those spans.

**How can i do this without loosing my caret position?**